# Right clicking inside an .fs file in VS2015 opens FSI

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2015, f#-interactive

Since I upgraded to VS2015 right clicking inside an F# .fs file no longer brings up the context menu but instead opens FSI. This happens on both my desktop and laptop, so it does not seem to be specific to the machine.

I have looked through the various menu and key binding options in VS2015 but cannot see anything that is bound to open FSI. (Under View > Other Windows > F# Interactive there is no shortcut listed).

Does anyone know why right clicking is opening FSI and how to change it back to opening the context menu?

Comment: Have you tried using the "Reset" button in Options under Environment/Keyboard?

Comment: @Kevin Just gave it a go and no joy I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4):

Kevin's suggestion of resetting the keyboard bindings got me thinking and I started disabling extensions to see if any of those were responsible.

With F# PowerTools and F# Outlining disabled I got the standard context menu back. I thought this might mean the problem was with F# Outlining, but after re-enabling both extensions I get a proper context menu when right clicking.

Disabling and re-enabling all F# related extensions seems to be the way to fix this.

Comment: Disabling and re-enabling F# Power Tools (from Tools -> Extensions and Updates) fixed this for me too - at least for now.

Comment: @Kit I still get this problem, although disabling/enabling can fix it temporarily. One thing I did notice is that if you leave interactive open then right clicking inside source files works as expected again, so it's a minor inconvenience more than anything.